# Generate WCF implementation/usage documentation from annotations or XML documentation inside project

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, documentation-generation, sandcastle

I have found plenty of ways to generate documentation for a webservice (doxygen, SandCastle,..) but I can't seem to find what I actually need.

We have a webservice written in C#.NET of which I have documented all the public methods using the standard XML documentation (summary-tags etc).

I would like to find a way to generate **usage documentation**, not generated documentation of how the project was set up. I don't need all the internal classes and methods to be included in the documentation.
The only thing that should be included are the public methods marked with [OperationContract] and their documentation.

I have found that with Sandcastle I can limit to those classes and methods, so that's a start. However we want to pass the documentation other developers which don't necessarily use .NET, so it would be nice to have a generated example of the exact SOAP call to make etc etc.

Can you advise me whether this can be done using Sandcastle, or should I be using a different approach?

Answer (score 1):

I thing WCFExtras is what are you looking for. Take a look: http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/